# SQL Server : get rows and sum from items in joined table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to return all rows in table `giftregistryitems` with an additional column that holds the sum of column `amount` in table `giftregistrypurchases` for the respective item in table `giftregistryitems`.

What I tried, but what returns NULL for `purchasedamount`, where I want `purchasedamount` to be the sum of the `amount` for THAT item, based on `giftregistrypurchases.itemid = giftregistryitems.id`:

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT 
        SUM(amount) 
    FROM
        giftregistrypurchases gps 
    WHERE  
        registryid = gi.registryid 
        AND gp.itemid = gps.itemid) as purchasedamount, * 
FROM 
    giftregistryitems gi
LEFT JOIN 
    giftregistrypurchases gp ON gp.registryid = gi.id
WHERE 
    gi.registryid = 2
```

How can I achieve what I need?

These are my table definitions and data.

A little explanation:

`[giftregistry]` is the general description of the list, the bridal couple in this is the only owner. They can add a text they want to send to the guests.

`[giftregistryitems]` contains the items the bridal couple is requesting. Here column amount is the total amount they want of that item, e.g. 6 coffee cups.

`[giftregistryemails]` contains the guests.

`[giftregistrypurchases]` contains which guest has purchased which amount of which item, e.g. guest nr. 3 has purchased 5 coffee cups (of the total 6 requested).

```
USE [tt]
GO
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[giftregistry] Script Date: 09-05-15 11:15:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[giftregistry](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[listuuid] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_giftregistry_listuuid] DEFAULT (newid()),
[userid] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[title] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[invitetext] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[createdate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_giftregistry_createdate] DEFAULT (getdate()),
CONSTRAINT [PK_giftregistry] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[giftregistryemails] Script Date: 09-05-15 11:15:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[giftregistryemails](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[registryid] [int] NOT NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[email] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
[pwd] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[sentdate] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_giftregistryemails_sentdate] DEFAULT (((1)/(1))/(1900)),
[createdate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_giftregistryemails_createdate] DEFAULT (getdate()),
CONSTRAINT [PK_giftregistryemails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[giftregistryitems] Script Date: 09-05-15 11:15:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[giftregistryitems](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[registryid] [int] NOT NULL,
[title] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
[ogimg] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[URL] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[trackingURL] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[amount] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[price] [int] NULL,
[createdate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_giftregistryitems_createdate] DEFAULT (getdate()),
CONSTRAINT [PK_giftregistryitems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[giftregistrypurchases] Script Date: 09-05-15 11:15:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[giftregistrypurchases](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[registryid] [int] NOT NULL,
[itemid] [int] NOT NULL,
[emailid] [int] NOT NULL,
[amount] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[createdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_giftregistrypurchases] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[giftregistry] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[giftregistry] ([id], [listuuid], [userid], [title], [description], [invitetext], [createdate]) VALUES (2, N'83875b62-3cc1-4516-b932-6e60a116cbff', N'32DD30EB-1691-457B-9FF5-FC41D687E579', N'My list', N'We''re getting married', N'Hey you guys coming too?', CAST(N'2015-04-29 21:21:53.813' AS DateTime))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[giftregistry] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[giftregistryemails] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[giftregistryemails] ([id], [registryid], [name], [email], [pwd], [sentdate], [createdate]) VALUES (2, 2, N'Peter', N'peter@hotmail.com', N'1234', CAST(N'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2015-05-02 22:01:53.783' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[giftregistryemails] ([id], [registryid], [name], [email], [pwd], [sentdate], [createdate]) VALUES (3, 2, N'Eric', N'eric@outlook.com', N'1234', CAST(N'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2015-05-02 22:01:53.783' AS DateTime))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[giftregistryemails] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[giftregistryitems] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[giftregistryitems] ([id], [registryid], [title], [ogimg], [description], [URL], [trackingURL], [amount], [price], [createdate]) VALUES (9, 2, N'1111', N'http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/281656969697-0-1/s-l1000.jpg', N'Surface Pro 3', N'http://www.ebay.com/itm/Microsoft-Surface-Pro-3-12-Tablet-256GB-SSD-Intel-Core-i7-Haswell-8GB-RAM-/281656969697', NULL, 1, 114998, CAST(N'2015-05-05 20:06:57.143' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[giftregistryitems] ([id], [registryid], [title], [ogimg], [description], [URL], [trackingURL], [amount], [price], [createdate]) VALUES (10, 2, N'Coffee cups', N'http://www.trouwen-feestartikelen.nl/images/rozenblaadjes-burgundy.jpg', N'Great cups', N'https://www.coffee.com/cups', NULL, 6, 25, CAST(N'2015-05-05 20:57:05.900' AS DateTime))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[giftregistryitems] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[giftregistrypurchases] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[giftregistrypurchases] ([id], [registryid], [itemid], [emailid], [amount], [createdate]) VALUES (3, 2, 9, 2, 5, CAST(N'2015-05-09 11:18:12.000' AS DateTime))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[giftregistrypurchases] OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[giftregistrypurchases] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_giftregistrypurchases_createdate] DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [createdate]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[giftregistryemails] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_giftregistryemails_giftregistry] FOREIGN KEY([registryid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[giftregistry] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[giftregistryemails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_giftregistryemails_giftregistry]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[giftregistryitems] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_giftregistryitems_giftregistry] FOREIGN KEY([registryid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[giftregistry] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[giftregistryitems] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_giftregistryitems_giftregistry]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[giftregistrypurchases] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_giftregistrypurchases_giftregistryitems] FOREIGN KEY([itemid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[giftregistryitems] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[giftregistrypurchases] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_giftregistrypurchases_giftregistryitems]
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'the unique code for this list' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'giftregistry', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'listuuid'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'the generated password for this list and this user' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'giftregistryemails', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'pwd'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'The user pasted URL is converted to a tracking URL where possible' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'giftregistryitems', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'trackingURL'
GO
```

Desired results:

```
purchasedamount id  registryid  title   ogimg   description URL amount  price   createdate
5   4   2   Coffee cups http://www.trouwen-feestartikelen.nl/images/rozenblaadjes-burgundy.jpg  Great cups  https://www.coffee.com/cups 6   25  57:05.9
0   5   2   Surface Pro 3   http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/281656969697-0-1/s-l1000.jpg  Surface Pro 3   http://www.ebay.com/itm/Microsoft-Surface-Pro-3-12-Tablet-256GB-SSD-Intel-Core-i7-Haswell-8GB-RAM-/281656969697 1   114998  06:57.1
```

Answer (score 0):

2 good ways to do that:

1) group by (a lot of things)

```
SELECT    
    SUM(gi.amount) as amount,
    gp.* 
FROM 
    giftregistryitems gi
LEFT JOIN 
    giftregistrypurchases gp ON gp.registryid = gi.id
WHERE 
    gi.registryid = 2
group by
    gp.Field1,
    gp.Field2 --All the gp fields :)
```

2) subquery (and i'd do this if i were you)

```
select
    *,
    (select sum(gi.amount) from giftregistryitems gi where gp.registryid = gi.id)
from
    giftregistrypurchases gp
```

cheers!

Comment: Hi, your code sums the `amount` from table `giftregistryitems`. That's not what I want:  I want to sum the `amount` column from table `giftregistrypurchases` for each item in `giftregistryitems`. How would I do that?

Comment: Hi Flo, I'm sorry but I'm not sure I'm following what you're trying to do. If you give me another example with numbers I'll be happy to provide another answer :) Reading your example again, I got to this conclusion, i'm sorry if it's no exactly what you want but I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are expecting :)

Comment: select
    *,
    (select sum(gp.amount) from giftregistrypurchases gp where gp.registryid = gi.registryid and gp.itemid = gi.id)
from
    giftregistryitems gi

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT gi.ID, SUM(gps.amount) as purchasedamount
FROM 
    giftregistryitems gi
LEFT JOIN 
    giftregistrypurchases gp ON gp.registryid = gi.id
WHERE 
    gi.registryid = 2
group by gi.id
```

That is a bad naming convention if registryid means something different in the two tables.